# QTP not recognizing application in production

Tags: qtp

We have a Java application that we have been testing in our test network without any issues for a couple years.  Recently we wanted to run a script in our production environment, but QTP doesn't recognize any of the objects in the application.  It only sees the entire window.  We have ruled out the build being different by taking our test version and running it on production with the resource files swapped with the same result.  We did the opposite with the production version in test and it worked just fine in test.

Any thoughts on what could be causing us the issue?

Comment: Have you verified that the required add-ins are selected?

Comment: Yes, the correct add-ins are selected and we are using the same version of QTP.

Comment: App is Web? Java? Are you using the same QTP PC for prod and test env  (probably not)?

Comment: No its a desktop application written in Swing and yes it's two separate computers.

Comment: QTP patches different? Extended playpack options in tools/options dialog different? If unsure, reinstall QTP on the prod robot PC (with clean uninstall). Still persist? Must be config issue outside of QTP. Different user running the app in prod? Some other super-cool policy file in place? Alternative desktop shell replacement active? :-O